# How to do nice statistics charts in Android?

Tags: android, graphics, charts, statistics, flat

I want to do some really nice stastics charts like Expense Manager, Runtastic, etc. 
Any idea how to do them? Is there an API to do that?
I want something like this:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You can give aChartEngine a try. You can see a video before deciding to use this or something else

Comment: Seems like a good option, but do you know if I can change all the designs textures and colors?

Comment: As far as I know there's a plenty of options - you can set all the colors you want and combine graps (i.e.: line and bar gaphs)

Comment: You can also try JasperReport graphing engine - all the fancy graphs you want. See [here](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library) for more info.

Comment: I resolved this using HoloGraphicLibrary, easy, simple and nice looking